# How to omit results of code nuggets within Razor view from being added to context/text

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I have the following code, as each line executes within the foreach its added to
the content and I just want the stuff in the `<text></text>` tags.

```
                <tfoot>

                @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PCbuild.Performance))
                {

                    @(ratings = PCbuild.Performance.Split(','))
                    foreach (var val in ratings)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @(score = Convert.ToInt32(val))
                                @(tempstring.AppendLine("<span class=\"RatingActive\">"))
                                @(tempstring.Append('█', score))
                                @(tempstring.AppendLine("</span>"))
                                @(tempstring.AppendLine("<span class=\"RatingUnactive\">"))
                                @(tempstring.Append('█', (10 - score)))
                                @(tempstring.AppendLine("</span>"))
                                <text>@tempstring.ToString()</text>
                                @tempstring.Clear()
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                </tfoot>
```

Comment: Custom Html helpers? View models? Hurry up before this view starts resembling spaghetti (it already has started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `@()`, use construct `@{}`. And also, after change, you won't have to repeat `@{}` on every line, just single start and end marker for single c# code block.

```
@{
  string s = "this is sample content";
  s += "this content won't be written to html output";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I don't think you need the tempstring at all

```
   @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PCbuild.Performance))
            {

                ratings = PCbuild.Performance.Split(',');
                foreach (var val in ratings)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @(score = Convert.ToInt32(val))
                            <span class="RatingActive">█ @score</span>
                            <span class="RatingUnactive">█ @(10 - score)</span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```